# Preserve round edges of UIButton

Tags: ios, swift2

trying to preserve the 'roundness' of a UIButton while user rotates the device:

```
func resizeButtons() {


        startButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        startButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.startButton.frame.size.width / 2
        startButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        startButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    }

override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {


        switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation{
        case .Portrait:
             self.resizeButtons()
        case .PortraitUpsideDown:
           self.resizeButtons()
        case .LandscapeLeft:
             self.resizeButtons()
        case .LandscapeRight:
             self.resizeButtons()
        default:
            print("default")
        }

    }
```

I am using auto layout and StoryBoards (button aspect ratio 1:1, and aspect ratio button to container view 1:3, button center horizontally and vertically to container).

The result is a bit cumbersome and 'ugly' as the device rotates the UIButton becomes a rounded corner rectangle and then full circle.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried just setting the cornerRadius to a static variable? Your frame width changes every time you rotate, causing it to become either a circle or a rounded rectangle. My preferred cornerRadius value is 5, e.g.
`button.layer.cornerRadius = 5`

I also wouldn't call the resize every time the orientation changes. Just set the variables in viewDidLoad() and call it a day

**EDIT:**
For a circle:

[image]

That is the UIButton. It is centered in the view, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: That would be ideal BUT this is not what I want. I want the circle to get bigger or smaller based on the ratio I have provided. I wish life was that simple! ;)

Comment: @GeorgeAsda ooh, I see, hmm, that wasnt really made clear. I've got a solution, I'll upload a screenshot of what works for me.

Comment: Thanks for that. In your screenshot how is this button getting bigger/ smaller when device is rotated? This looks more like a static dimension of 100 with corner radius of 50 to produce a circle. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GeorgeAsdah yeah I could only get it to work with a static size.